# What is the Arccos method in C#?

Tags: c#

Which is the arccos method in c#? 
I found one acos but i am not sure its the correct one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.acos.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Math.Acos() is the cos<sup>-1</sup> function in .NET, so you have it right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the one.

[Arccosine](http://www.icoachmath.com/math_dictionary/arccosine.html):

> Arccosine is the inverse function of cosine. It is also written as
>   arccos or cos- 1. If y = cos x, then x = arccos y.

The definition on the page that you linked to:

> Returns the angle whose cosine is the specified number.